# Machine Learning: features that don't apper

Tags: machine-learning

I have a naive question in the field of Machine Learning.

I have unigrams as features and [idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) as feature values.

The question is how to calculate idf of the unigram that does appear in the test set and doesn't appear in the train set.
The idf formula is the following log(N/D), where N - total number of documents, D - is a number of document where our specific unigram appears, but what to do when D=0.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform [additive smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing) by always adding 1 or some other constant to D.